power bi division variable measure
I need to create a measure that performs a division in a way or another depending on if the amounts of sales and budget are positive or negative. The desired output will be something like what you can see in the image and the division will be:

Positive numbers: sales/budget.
Negative numbers: 2-(sales/budget)

I can't find a way to make it work properly. I have tried function divide(sales,budget)-2 but it's not dynamic so the results are incorrect.
Thanks.
enter image description here

do you wants the second logic when both sales and budgets are negative? or any one?

Hello and many thanks for your reply. The logic should be like this: if we have positive numbers then divide sales by budget (sales/budget) and if one number is negative (sales or budget), then should divide like this: 2-(sales/budget). Thank you very much.

Please edit your question to show what you have tried, and include how the result differed from your expected results.

% = DIVIDE('Table'[SALES],'Table'[BUDGET]) + IF(OR(SIGN('Table'[BUDGET])=-1,SIGN('Table'[SALES])=-1),-2,0)



Hello, is it possible to create the same measure but with the already created ones for sales an budget? Something like: % = DIVIDE([sales], [budget])+IF(OR(SIGN([BUDGET] = -1, SIGN ([SALES] = -1),-2,0)? Thank you!

@Ruben ??? I have no idea what you are asking.  ??? You show almost the same formula I provided which is doing that.

Hello, I wanted to ask if the formula you provided me will work using the measures I have for sales and budget with the modifications I showed instead of the table. Don't know if I explain myself any better... Many thanks

@Ruben What happened when you tried it? I would think it might work, but that should be simple for you to test.

Thanks Ron I think I missed a parenthesis or something the first time. It works, thank you so much.
